# PHP COM('word.application') functions and methods parameters issue

Tags: php, vba, ms-word, com

I'm using php and new COM('word.application') to manipulate a .doc file (add and edit fields), I'm on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with apache 2.4.25 x64 and php 7.0.17 x64.

So far I made a simple code which work great, but I have an issue when using functions with multiple parameters like this one

```
$word->Documents[1]->Protect(3, false, 'mypassword', false, false);
```

I get the following error :

[Erreur] Impossible de lancer le connecteur Microsoft Office Word. : com_exception: Parameter 4: Le type ne correspond pas

Approx translation in english :

[Error] Impossible to laungh the Microsoft Office Word connector : com_exception: Parameter 4: type does not correspond

In VBA code like this it's working

```
ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
```

According to the doc found in VBA

[image: And this : https://msdn.microsof]t.com/en-us/library/office/aa220366(v=office.11).aspx

Parameters 2, 4 and 5 should be booleans, so I don't know why I'm getting this error. If i remove parameters 4 and 5, I get the same error but on parameter 2.

With some searches i looked at the object new VARIANT() but it didn't work too.

I have also the problem with $this->Documents[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXc4X.png)->SaveAs()

```
$fileName = "D:\\test.doc";
$this->Documents[1]->SaveAs($fileName);
```

It works.

According to the doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas(v=vs.120).aspx) I should be able to use a second parameter like this :

```
$fileName = "D:\\test.doc";
$fileFormat = 0;
$this->Documents[1]->SaveAs($fileName, $fileFormat);
```

Like this I have the error "Parameter 0: Le type ne correspond pas" (Type does not correspond).

In VBA it's working differently, maybe I'm doing something wrong ...

Much thanks if you help me :)

edit : full example code

```
<?php

$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Cannot create Word object");
echo "com object created<br>";
$word->Visible = false;
$word->WindowState = 2;
$word->DisplayAlerts = false;
$word->Documents->Open("D:\\test.doc");
echo "document loaded<br>";

$import = $word->Documents[1]->VBProject->VBComponents->Import("D:\\fr.mac");
$import->name = "Macrofr";

$myModule = $word->Documents[1]->VBProject->VBComponents->Import("D:\\test1.mac");
$myModule->name = "MacroInit";

$myModule2 = $word->Documents[1]->VBProject->VBComponents->Import("D:\\test2.mac");
$myModule2->name = "MacroFonction";

$myModule3 = $word->Documents[1]->VBProject->VBComponents->Import("D:\\test3.frm");
$myModule3->name = "MacroProgression";


$word->Documents[1]->Protect(3,false,'motdepasse',false,false); // (type de protection,noReset,mdp)

$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("D:\\doc_with_macro.doc", 0);
$word->Documents[1]->Close();
echo "closing doc<br>";

$word->Quit();
$word = null;
echo "end<br>";
```

Comment: I've edited my post and changed a little the question, any help is welcomed :)

Comment: Please post more of your code block and not few line snippets. We need to see how you initialize COM object.

Comment: HI, I've edited my 1st post and added the full code.
I've found something ...

I was using apache 2.4.25 x64 vc14 + php 7.0.17 x64 vc14 + office 2010 x64,

I've changed apache and php with the same versions but x86 ... and all is working now ... so my problem is solved ... but i'm curious why it isnt working with x64 versions

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I see in this code is related to `protect` `function`. First parameter must be `VARIANT` like this :

```
$word->Documents[1]->Protect(
        new VARIANT(3, VT_I4),
        false,
        'Your password',
        false,
        true
  );
```